# How to know when asynchronous functions finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a function that calls an asynchronous function multiple times in a loop.

```
function myFunc() {
    var things = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    $.each(things, asyncFunc);

    alert('Things ' + things.join() + ' have all been processed.');
}

function asyncFunc(key, value) {
    $.post('api.php', value: thing);
}
```

I want to continue only when all asynchronous calls have finished.

I could make `asyncFunc` return a deferred object, and call `.resolve()` in the `$.post.done` method, but then how could I block the `.each` loop and continue only when the `asyncFunc` is finished?

What other ways are there to continue only when all calls to `asyncFunc` are done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pass a *callback* into `asyncFunc`
2. In the *callback*, have a counter based on `things.length`
3. Count how many times *callback* has been called
4. If the counter indicated more to go, end the *callback*
5. If the counter indicates that this is the last time, continue invocation

e.g. callback

```
var count = things.length,
    callback = function () {
        if (0<--count) return;
        // do stuff
    };
```

Comment: Ah, nice. I already have a callback in `asyncFunc`, so I just added the extra callback call to the end of the current callback. Anyway, could you make your answer show the whole working code for new people to discover please?